# Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid when I do a google login using firebase and ionic v3

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, oauth

I’m facing a problem when I try to use the FireBase Google login.
When I log in to Google successfully and when it returns back on App iOS, I get this error:

> Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid msg

I do not know where the problem could be, because in Android, it works.

My system information:

- Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
- Ionic Framework Version: 3.9.2
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 3.2.0
- ios-deploy version: 2.0.0
- ios-sim version: 3.0.0
- OS: macOS
- Node Version: v6.9.4
- Xcode version: Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

Comment: someone figure this out, it's driving me nuts

Comment: Hi Ryan, i'm using this plugin (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) and i think the new version... its fixed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using this plugin (github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) and i think the new version... its fixed.